# Load an assembly from a DLL in Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, windows-rt

I am trying to write a code editor in WinRT that will make the Surface RT and Surface 2 a viable device for people who write code using Visual Studio by bringing light weight code editing functionality to Windows RT in a Windows Store app (No debugging, obviously, just editing files in SkyDrive that are used on a real PC in Visual Studio). This app would include intellisense-like features as a key functionality, and to do this, I would have the user browse to all of the .DLL and .EXE files that their project references. Outside of WinRT, this is relatively simple, but I don't see how to load an assembly from a DLL in WinRT. Is it possible? Remember, I just need to get the string data containing the classes and namespaces contained within the library, and the names of the members of those classes and nothing more.

If it's not possible, it's a shame that a developer like me has to be stopped by all of the restrictions in Windows RT. I am, after all, just trying to write a virus by loading external DLLs and reading the names of the classes, and not running any of the code (sarcasm alert).

Answer (score 0):

Would you really need the dll's and exe's or do you just need the data that will be used? Why not extract the data that your application will use and store that information instead of the complete dll's and exe's?

Comment: That would be good if there is a way to do it. Do you know how to do that? On the desktop, I can load an Assembly object from a file, and I can browse its types.

Comment: I probably would make my own object that stores the information and a tool to extract the information from a dll or exe using reflection.